# sinon spy is not fired inside the mongodb findOne callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to test a similar code to this

```
testFind = (cb) ->
  cb()
wrapper = (fn) ->
  (req, mongodb) ->
    users = mongodb.db.collection("user")
    # fired here
    fn req, mongodb

    testFind (err, user) ->
      #fired here
      fn req, mongodb

    users.findOne
      "username": "user1"
    , (err, user) ->
      console.log "user is valid", user
      console.log "req.done is still a spy object", req.done
      #not fired here
      fn req, mongodb



test = wrapper (req, mongodb) ->
  req.done 200

module.exports = test
```

and pass a spy for `req.done`. As mentioned in the comments above, the spy is never fired inside the mongodb callback, even though it is a valid spy object and the callback is called. But it works outside of it. It also works if I replace the mongodb findOne with a local sample function that calls the callback. This is the test code

```
mongodb = {}
describe.only "test:", ->
  before (done) ->
    this.timeout(5000)
    MongoClient.connect "mongodb://localhost/test", (err, db) ->
      if err?
        done err
      mongodb.db = db
      done()
  it "should fire complete", ->
    @req =
      complete: sinon.spy().named("complete")
    test @req, mongodb
    @req.complete.should.have.been.calledThrice
```